# Using iterator for slicing an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, object-slicing

I was looking at this python code that I need some explanation with:

```
arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5]
arr = arr[next((i for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x != 0), len(arr)):]
```

This code would remove the leading zeroes from the array, I am trying to understand how it works. I understand that we created an iterator that would iterate over all elements of `arr` but 0 values, and next would iterate only till length of array (not inclusive).

But how are these indices returned by next, combine to form an array?

Comment: what exactly do you think is wrong here ? exact same code executes to create [1 2 3 4 5]

Comment: It might be, but I still want to understand how it works.

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't read carefully. Answer coming up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the code step by step. You want to slice off the initial zeros. If you knew the index of the first non-zero element, `n`, the expression would look like

```
arr = arr[n:]
```

That's basically what we have here, with `n = next((i for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x != 0), len(arr))`.

In general, the two-arg form of `next` will return the second argument as a marker instead of raising a `StopIteration` should the iterator run out. That's what the `len(arr)` is for. If all the elements are zero, the expression becomes

```
arr = arr[len(arr):]  # obviously empty
```

If there is a non-zero element, the `next` call will find its index (enabled with `enumerate`), and return it.

Comment: For some reason, I thought next would return an iterator, my bad. This is straightforward. I will mark it as answer for readers.